# WPF GradientBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How Many type of gradient brushes are available like LinearGradientBrush, SolidColorBrush?
and when we create a GradientStop how the offset works?

```
        LinearGradientBrush LGB = new LinearGradientBrush();
        LGB.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        LGB.EndPoint = new Point(0, 1);
        LGB.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255,251,255) , 0));
        LGB.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(206,207,222), 1));
        LGB.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(0, 247, 0), 2));
        rect.Fill = LGB;
```

Why the third one "Color.FromRgb(0, 247, 0)" is not reflecting?

Please suggest,where i am wrong?

Comment: @Jaswant: you should do the polite and proper thing and accept the best answer / the one that really solved you problem. To accept the answer, please click on the check mark to the left of the answer below the "0" with the up- and down-arrow. If someone helps you - please be so kind as to accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GradientStop.Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientstop.offset.aspx) property is a value which ranges from 0.0 to 1.0. From the MSDN documentation:

> A value of 0.0 specifies that the stop is positioned at the beginning of the gradient vector, while a value of 1.0 specifies that the stop is positioned at the end of the gradient vector.

Change your second stop's offset to 0.5 and your third's to 1.0 and it should work.